# ScrollView content pushed out of scrollable content when adding fragment to it programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I have a ScrollView with content already added to it. The bottom element is a RelativeLayout that I use as a placeholder for a fragment that replaces it at a later stage. This fragment contains a few GridLayouts that get populated by pictures as the backend can load them in. When this happens the content above the added fragment gets pushed up and out of the screen.

The scrollview resizes correctly but the top contents can't be scrolled to and there's an empty space in the bottom of equivalent size to the content that got pushed off the screen. It looks like this (arrow is where the fragment gets loaded in:

[image: Scrollview contents pushed off screen]
This is the layout of the scrollview:

```
<ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/home_view_scroll
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true">

   ...........

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_to_be_replaced_by_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/other_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
</ScrollView>
```

The relative layout then gets replace by a simple Fragment replace transaction. The fragment contains a LinearLayout filled with three GridLayouts as well as dividers between them. The GridLayouts get populated by CustomViews that load an image and place a text under the image.

I've tried adding the layout_to_be_replaced_by_fragment layout as a bottom aligned. I've tried invalidating the root view after all GridLayout images are loaded. I'm probably missing something basic, but where.... any ideas?

Full layouts upon request (it's alarm_overlay_contacts_layout in the bottom of the main layout that gets replaced):
[Main layout](http://tny.cz/f1601262), [Fragment Layout](http://tny.cz/6275c999)

Comment: Could you post full xml?

Comment: They're a bit long for SO, but added tinypaste links.